# what is a 'valid' std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

`operator bool` is described: "Checks whether the stored callable object is valid".

Presumably a default constructed `std::function` is not valid but is this the only case?

Also, how does it check whether it is valid?

Is the case where `operator()` raises `std::bad_function_call` exactly the case where the object is not valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's poorly written as is, your confusion is justified. By "valid" they mean "has a target".

A `std::function` "has a target" when it's been assigned a function:

```
std::function<void()> x; // no target
std::function<void()> y = some_void_function; // has target

x = some_other_void_function; // has target
y = nullptr; // no target

x = y; // no target
```

They should have either defined "valid" before they used it, or simply stuck with the official wording.

Comment: OK, so the check for validity is just the type check and calling a default constructed `std::function` is exactly the case where `std::bad_function_call` is raised, yup?

Comment: @user710408: I don't know what you mean by "the check for validity is just the type check". Validity (now assuming the definition "has a target") is determined at run-time, type-checking happens at compile-time. And bad function call happens whever the function isn't valid (has no target), be that from default construction or being explicitly assigned `nullptr`.

Comment: I don't think I knew what I meant either! Thanks :)

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The language standard says

> `explicit operator bool() const noexcept;`
>
> Returns: true if *this has a target, otherwise false.

Meaning  that the `function` has anything to call. The default constructed `function` obviously does not.